# Automatic test report generation in Datadog

Tags: api, automated-tests, reporting, rest-assured, datadog

Is it possible to generate auto API test report using Datadog? :)
I'm creating a project in Java using Rest Assured and Hamcrest. I have the project on gitlab and I would like the tests to be automatically run. Based on them, I would like to receive a report :).
At first I through I could use a allure but my supervisor asked me if I could do it in Datadog.
I tried to find background material on this subject, but failed :(
I will be grateful for every link with supporting materials :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you use for build tool maven or gradle?

I think this should work for you:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/continuous_integration/tests/java

Comment: Hi, I use Gradle :)

Comment: Have you checked the above the link. This should work for you.

Comment: I haven't look at that yet, but i will. In first look i think it won't be so easy for me 

Comment: It should be pretty quick actually. You need to change the gradle file only. There is step by step procedure when you select agent or agentless configuration for gradle. https://docs.datadoghq.com/continuous_integration/tests/java/?tab=cloudciprovideragentless

Comment: you have right. with my junior experience I made first report in few minutes. thank you very much 